# Erro ao fazer conexao com server php

Tags: php

Estou recebendo o erro ao tentar fazer conexão com o banco de dados.

**configuration.php**

```
class Connection {
    private static $connection = null;
    public static get() {
          if (self::$connection == null) { self::$connection = mysqli_connect("mysql.uhserver.com", "user", "passw","db" ); }
          return self::$connection;
    }
}
```

**page php**

```
  header("content-type:application/json");

  require_once '../includes/configuration.php';

  $result= mysqli_query(Connection::get(),"SELECT Id, Titulo, Descricao, date_format(DataEvento, '%d/%m/%Y') AS DataEvento FROM agenda WHERE DATAEVENTO >= NOW() ORDER BY DATACADASTRO" ) or die(mysqli_error());
```

**Erro**

> syntax error, unexpected 'get' (T_STRING), expecting variable
>   (T_VARIABLE)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Faltou um `function` antes da definição do método `get`. Sem isso ele confunde o `static` com uma propriedade e espera por uma variável.

Segue uma versão simplificada funcionando:

```
<?php

class Connection 
{
    private static $connection = null;

    public static function get()
    {
          if (self::$connection == null) {
              self::$connection = mysqli_connect("mysql.uhserver.com", "user", "passw","db" );
          }

          return self::$connection;
    }
}

$result = mysqli_query(Connection::get(), "SELECT Id, Titulo, Descricao, date_format(DataEvento, '%d/%m/%Y') AS DataEvento FROM agenda WHERE DATAEVENTO >= NOW() ORDER BY DATACADASTRO" ) or die(mysqli_error());
```

Se você está começando, recomendo dar uma olhada em PDO ao invés das funções de `mysql_*`. Tem um [artigo](https://code.tutsplus.com/pt/tutorials/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use--net-24059) que pode te ajudar.

Comment: Só um detalhe: ele está usando a API `mysqli`, não `mysql`, então não teria porque trocar por PDO sem necessidade. Só comentando, dado seu adendo no final da resposta.

Comment: Caro gmsantos sua resposta esta corretíssima de o +1 já esta garantido, mas tenho que concordar com o @AndersonCarlosWoss sobre o final da resposta, não tem vantagem alguma real entre ambas APIs, tanto que o argumento for migrar de banco mais fácil, isso é um engano, porque as sintaxes de bancos são diferentes, talvez em um sistema de ORM (escrito em PDO e sem queries) seria vantajoso, mas ai o proprio ORM internamente é quem definiria isto. O link do artigo que vc citou é bom, mas não é o caso aqui e nem reforça nada sobre o uso de PDO > mysqli.

Comment: Não tinha reparado que era `mysqli_*`, mas ainda sim prefiro recomendar o PDO por ele abstrair a API de comunicação com o banco de dados e ter uma abordagem orientada a objetos. Sim, você pode usar mysqli orientado a objetos também, mas ainda sim é uma implementação amarrada ao um banco de dados específico.

Comment: Podem existir queries que funcionam em um DB ou outro, mas o SQL é um padrão e a maioria das queries se escritas corretamente com o que diz a especificação irá funcionar sem problemas.

Answer (score 3):

Problema é que você não definiu `get()` como uma função dentro da classe:

```
class Connection {
    private static $connection = null;
    public static function get() {
    if (self::$connection == null) { 
        self::$connection = mysqli_connect("mysql.uhserver.com", "user", "passw","db" ); }
        return self::$connection;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Simples, você colocou o get separado do static  e o function 
Antes:

```
public static get() {
```

Depois:

```
public function staticGet() {
```

recomendo que você utilize a conexão VIA: PDO
aqui para o site da W3C pra saber como fazer conexão PDO:https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp

Não esqueça de colocar o set da conexão, pois você está usando ela como private e não como pubçic ou protected

Comment: Caro Jiren, static é uma palavra chave da linguagem para usar chamadas estaticas, isso é nativo da linguagem (de muitas linguagens inclusive), não tem sentido algum juntar ambos, ai deixaria de ser estatico. Recomendo que aprenda o básico da linguagem antes de arriscar a responder e acabar ensinando errado as pessoas.

Comment: Desculpe-me, mas sua resposta não fez nem o mínimo de sentido, nem quando disse que o static deveria ser junto com get, nem quando indicou PDO, muito menos quanto ter esquecido do set.